# Pass custom model *with List<CustClass>* through ajax call

Tags: c#, ajax, jsonresult

I am having a bit of trouble passing my json string to the jsonResult within my controller. All the first-level variables come in fine except for the `List<CustClass>` which always returns a **default empty list** when it should be filled with the **list of objects (List<>)** I passed in.

The ajax call that looks along the lines of:

```
var model = {
    Id: id,
    Name: name,
    Items: [{
        Name: itemName[0],
        Color: itemColor[0]
    },{
        Name: itemName[1],
        Color: itemColor[2]
    }]
};

$.ajax({
    url: "/@path",
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify(model),
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    cache: false,
    traditional: true
});
```

With my C# model looking along the lines of

```
public class MyModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public class Item {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Color { get; set; }
    }
    public List<Item> Items = new List<Item>();
}
```

And the result:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult MyResult(MyModel model)
{
    // Do Stuff
}
```

What am I doing wrong here? Is this even possible to do?

Comment: did you try not to instantiate the list?

Comment: @Katana what do you mean by this?

Comment: public List<Item> Items = {get; set;}

Comment: @Katana that was exactly the problem... Didn't realise that a {get;set } method was needed for variables to pass through a result.

Comment: is it working now?

Comment: Yes, post your answer and ill set it as correct

Comment: thanks :) i posted it already

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont instantiate your list to map it properly. Since binding of model takes place after instantiation of the class.

```
public class MyModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public class Item {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Color { get; set; }
    }
    public List<Item> Items {get; set;}
}
```